# If I move a github repo to another user, how does this affect the package on npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, npm

I wanted to move a github repo over to another user or organization, this repo has been published to npm as a package.

My concern is what happens to older versions of this package which users may try to install?

For example assume my node package is called **node-awesome-package**

Versions 0.0.1 - 0.0.9 were published with my own repo **https://github.com/StevenIseki/node-awesome-package**

I then moved this repo over to the **someorg** organization  **https://github.com/someorg/node-awesome-package**

Then version 1.0.0 is published.

If a user downloads the earlier versions 0.0.1 to 0.0.9 will everything be okay for them?

Comment: actually I have just attempted it and it seems to work okay. It picks up the old .tgz from https://registry.npmjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Update the repository/issues urls in the package.json, bump the version (the patch level is fine, ex: `x.x.1 to x.x.2`). then publish... the package info in npm should update relatively quickly, you may see cached results for a few minutes.